# return QFile::copy from web

Tags: c++, qt, qfile

When moving files around locally within my project I'm able to use

```
return QFile::copy(fromPath, toPath);
```

I need to do something similar but with the fromPath being located on the web.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QFile works with local file only.

If you want to copy remote file from web, then you need to download it using [QNetworkAccessManager](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtnetwork/qnetworkaccessmanager.html)

Answer (score 0):

Install on your source and destination machine ssh. Then do a scp via QProcess.
This is one way. The best? Depends on your requirements. You can also write a program for your destination machine, which accepts incoming TCP connections from your source machine. Then you connect via QTcpSocket and send your data. Qt4 has a QFtp class. Never used it. Is also a dead end, since it does not exist anymore in Qt5. But maybe it is good enough for your current needs.

I hope you did not expect a more specific answer. There is not 'remoteQFile::copy' command. And there is no general 'best way'.